# Назначить права суперпользователя в ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, root

Поставил впервые ubuntu, потом lamp сервер для php. 
Нужно создать файл в /var/www/ . Но ни вручную, ни в терминале не даёт система сделать это. Тогда написал в терминале команду 
`sudo -i` , назначив себе права суперпользователя. Теперь могу создать файл в терминале с помощью команды touch.

Остаётся вопрос - почему я не могу создать вручную файл, т.е. банально правой клавишей мыши, как в windows, создать файл. Что для этого нужно? Как назначить себе права на постоянные любые действия с папками и файлами?

Comment: вопрос неясен. ведь вы же создали файл именно «вручную».

Comment: подредактировал описание сути вопроса

Answer (score 3):

> Поставил впервые ubuntu, потом lamp сервер для php. Нужно создать файл в /var/www/

назначьте *docroot* вашего сайта в каталог, находящийся внутри вашего домашнего каталога:

```
DocumentRoot /home/пользователь/www
```

где `/home/пользователь` — это ваш домашний каталог. веб-сервер после этого надо будет перезапустить.

ну и не забудьте создать этот каталог («мышкой» или «вручную»: `mkdir ~/www`).

теперь без всяких «дополнительных прав» вы сможете создавать/редактировать/удалять файлы/каталоги вашего сайта.

Comment: пасиб, но эт понятно. Мне интересно доступиться именно в дефолтный каталог /var/www/ и получить там возможность делать манипуляции с папками и файлами

Comment: предложенное мною — наиболее «правильный» вариант. то, что вам предлагают в других ответах (сделать каталог доступным для записи всем пользователям) — абсолютно «неправильно». чуть менее «неправильно» (но тоже очень плохо) — сделать вашего пользователя владельцем каталога `/var/www`: `sudo chown -R $USER /var/www`.

Comment: ваше желание перенести «как есть» привычки из одной операционной системы в другую — вполне понятно, но, увы, бессмысленно. постарайтесь обзавестись «новыми привычками», более подходящими к новому окружению.

Comment: ну так а пользователя то нет. Я для себя, как владельца ноутбука хочу сделать.

Comment: пользователей в вашей машине гораздо более одного. можете сами подсчитать: `wc -l /etc/passwd`

Comment: выдало 36 /etc/passwd

Comment: а почему так? что это за пользователи?

Comment: посмотрите сами: `cat /etc/passwd`

Comment: ещё один момент протестил - создал файл 1.php с помощью $ sudo chmod ugo+w /var/www/html/ и сделал запись в этот файл и позволило сохранить даже. Потом в браузере запустил localhost/1.php - всё сработало. Но так лучше не делать? Лучше я так понимаю тут создавать /home/пользователь/www    ?верно?

Comment: cat /etc/passwd посомтрел, я так понимаю что эти "пользователи" - службы разные.

Comment: @Sven, да. Хорошим тоном при написании демонов - запускать каждого под своим пользователем. Это и безопасность и удобство в обслуживании.

Answer (score 0):

Потому, что по умолчанию файловый менеджер вашей ОС не запускается с правами суперпользователя. А директория, в который вы хотите создать файл не позволяет вам это сделать из-за отсутствия у вашего пользователя прав на запись.

Для решения этого вопроса вам необходимо либо присвоить права записи для данной директории при помощи утилиты chmod:

```
$ sudo chmod ugo+w /var/www/
```

Либо локально в терминале использовать sudo для выполнения команды touch с правами суперпользователя:

```
$ sudo touch FILENAME
```

однако данные действия с sudo придется выполнять каждый раз при создании файла.

Системой, выполняется запрет на запись данных прежде всего для обеспечения их внутренней безопасности. Можете подробней почитать про утилиту chmod (english):
[Archwiki::File permissions and attributes.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=File_permissions_and_attributes&redirect=no#Changing_permissions)

Comment: о, получилось с помощью $ sudo chmod ugo+w /var/www/. спасибо! Я теперь создал вручную файл, сделал там код, но сохранить файл не даёт. Что делать? Надо было к этой команде $ sudo chmod ugo+w /var/www/  ещё что-то добавить чтобы позволило записывать в файл и сохранять его?

Comment: Можете текст выдаваемой ошибки подсказать?

Comment: ошибки никакой не выдавал. Просто в файле, который был открыт текстовым редактором gedit, кнопка "Сохранить" - вбитая, не кликабельная, т.е. сохранить не могу изменения там.

Comment: Значит вы все еще не имеете прав на запись в данную директорию, проверьте права на запись для данной директории:

Comment: sudo ls -ld /var/www/

Comment: пишет drwxrwxrwx Я не имею прав записи в сам файл, который в этой директории /var/www/

Comment: Тогда вам необходимо разрешить запись в конкретный файл, при помощи того же chmod. Но это не лучшая идея, разрешать запись в директорию любым пользователям. А тем более ваш комментарий с назначением таких прав доступа всей файловой системе.

Comment: а что значит пользователям? я хочу себе как владельцу ноутбука, скажем так, назначить эти права. У меня нет других пользователей тут.

Comment: Почитайте пожалуйста какими правами обладает суперпользователь и в чем его отличие от локального пользователя. Вот ссылочка на документацию вашей ОС: http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE_ubuntu_server/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C/user_management

Comment: т.е. суперпользователь - это сама ubuntu? А я и остальные другие - это просто юзеры, которые временно можем повышать себе права?

Comment: ещё один момент протестил - создал файл 1.php с помощью $ sudo chmod ugo+w /var/www/html/ и сделал запись в этот файл и позволило сохранить даже. Потом в браузере запустил localhost/1.php - всё сработало. Но так лучше не делать? Лучше я так понимаю тут создавать /home/пользователь/www    ?верно?

Comment: В зависимости от ваших потребностей для конкретной задачи. В конкретно описанном вами случае, работайте с пользовательскими файлами в своей домашней папке, и не изменяйте права на системные папки, так как это может негативно сказаться на стабильности работы вашей системы.

Answer (score -1):

> Как назначить себе права на постоянные любые действия с папками и файлами?

Самый простой вариант, назначить пароль root:

```
sudo passwd root
```

Выйти из графического окружения и зайти уже под пользователем root. Тогда никаких ограничений на работу с файлами и папками не будет в графической среде, мышкой можно будет создавать файлы в любой папке.

Но, конечно, такой вариант не рекомендуется. Лучше пользоваться отдельным файловым менеджером, который загружать с правами суперпользователя:

```
sudo mc
```

Откроет двухпанельный менеджр похожий на FAR в Windows.

```
sudo krusader
```

Откроет менеджер похожий на total comander, запустив его таким образом - ограничений на работу с файлами не будет.

Ну только предварительно установить их надо для этого:

```
sudo apt-get install mc krusader
```

Если двухпанельный не нужен, можно запустить обычный:

```
sudo nautilus
```

В открывшемся окне файлового менеджера будут неограниченные права, создавать и редактировать файлы можно будет мышкой без запроса прав суперпользователя.

Comment: Не соглашусь с вами. Нет никаких особых файловых менеджеров для sudo. Подойдёт абсолютно любой, не нужно здесь ничего дополнительно устанавливать (можно конечно, но это никак не относится к вопросу).