# Смена прав доступа на директорию в Ubuntu 16.04.1 TLS

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, vps

Жесть, конечно, программирование легче освоить, нежели администрирование сервера. Постоянно что-то отказывается работать.

Хоть убейте, но у меня не выходит сменить ни права доступа, ни владельца папки с веб-приложениями (/var/www). Создал юзера для терминала superadmin. Прописывал, и от его имени, и от имени root'a:

sudo chown -R superadmin /var/www

sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www

Даже 777 в chmod не помогает. Не могу ничего ни создавать, ни изменять в директории.

FileZilla пишет следующее:

Статус:   Начинаю закачивать D:\test.php

Команда:   CWD /var/www/html

Ответ:   250 Directory successfully changed.

Команда:   TYPE A

Ответ:   200 Switching to ASCII mode.

Команда:   PASV

Ответ:   227 Entering Passive Mode (*скрылIP*).

Команда:   STOR test.php

Ответ:   550 Permission denied.

Ошибка:   Критическая ошибка при передаче файлов

Тыкнете носом где я туплю...

Comment: используйте для подключения протокол *ssh*, а не *ftp*. а ещё лучше сделать так: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/586127/178576

Comment: @alexanderbarakin 
Здравствуйте! А по SSH же файлы передавать не очень удобно. Вот как вы посоветовали, сделал директорию сайта в директории своего пользователя /home/user/www/site. Но блин и через FileZill'u и через TotalCommander по FTP протоколу отказываются туда файлы перелетать -=(((

Comment: примонтировать файловую систему можно не только по протоколу ftp, но и по протоколу ssh. для пользователя это выглядит абсолютно идентично.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, хорошо, спасибо, углублюсь, почитаю про это.

Comment: не уверен, что надо что-то «читать» по этому поводу. скорее просто другой пункт в диалоге подключения надо выбрать.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, ну не скажите, почитать в любом аспекте IT всегда что найдётся, тем более, если есть желание копать глубоко. Похоже, что ни FileZilla, ни TotalComander не поддерживают протокол SSH. И везде описываются способы копирования файлов по протоколу SSH лишь с использованием консоли.

Comment: [filezilla](http://filezilla.ru/documentation/Howto), [totalcommander](http://popel-studio.com/blog/article/rabota-s-sftp-v-total-commander.html), [winscp](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinSCP), много их…